# Remove next empty row from text

Tags: php, regex, replace

From text:

```
Text...
Target row


Text...
```

I need **remove** row with string '**Target row**' **and the next empty row**. So I need to get:

```
Text...

Text...
```

Comment: What's your linebreak? `\n` or `\r\n`?

Comment: What input format are you using (text, array of lines?) and how do you detect "Target row"?

Comment: Text is from textarea. Target row is detect by string 'Target row'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace('/^Target row\r?\n\r?\n/m', '', $subject);
```

if empty lines must really not contain anything, not even spaces/tabs. If spaces/tabs are allowed, use

```
$result = preg_replace('/^Target row[ \t]*\r?\n[ \t]*\r?\n/m', '', $subject);
```

Comment: You can use `\s*`, can't you? Or would it eat also newlines? (`\s*?` than)

Comment: @Vyktor: Yes it would, and he only wants to remove a single empty line. And `\s*?` is useless since it will preferably match the empty string and so not remove anything.

Answer (score 0):

You've got few "big options".

#### Replace characters within a text:

```
$req = ''; // Partial string to get matched
$length = 0; // If you had a full string not partial, use strlen here

// Now find beginning, don't forget to check with === false
$pos = strpos( $text, $req);
$end = strpos( $text, "\n", $pos+1);

// If you don't have criteria that match from start
$start = strrpos( $text, "\n", $pos-1);
// And build resulting string (indexes +/-2, do your job):
$result = substr( $text, 0, $start-1) . substr( $text, $end+2);
```

#### Match results with [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

If you need to match more complex patter you could use `preg_match_all()` with flag `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` (to get start offset) and than use the same algorithm as previous example (previous should be much more effective).

#### Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

<sub>As Tim Pietzcker suggested, but this solution doesn't care about spaces in free row</sub>

```
$result = preg_replace('/^Target row\r?\n\s*\r?\n/m', '', $subject);
```

#### Use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`next`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php)

```
$array = explode( "\n", $text);
// I would use this only when loading file with:
$array = file( 'file.txt');

while( $row = next( $array)){
  if( matches( $row)){ // Apply whatever condition you need
    $key1 = key( $array);
    next( $array); // Make sure it's not === false
    $key2 = key( $array);

    unset( $array[$key1]);
    unset( $array[$key2]);
    break;
  }
}
```

#### When loading from file with [`fgets`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

```
$fp = fopen( 'file.txt', 'r') or die( 'Cannot open');
while( $row = fgets( $fp)){
  if( matched( $row)){
    fgets( $fp);// Just skip line
  } else {
    // Store row
  }
}
```